# How to output data from iSQL to Excel file with column names?

Tags: mysql, sybase, sap-iq

I am trying to query using `iSQL` client and export the query results to an `Excel` with column name. When I try below script error message saying:

> Invalid Format "Excel".

Other than `Excel` format (ASCII, CSV, etc) all are working but no column name.

```
SQL query 
    select  * from siebel.S_ORG_EXT;  
    OUTPUT TO 'C:\Siebel SQLs\Account.xls' FORMAT EXCEL
    DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '' ;
```

Comment: Removed indent from text and indented the code so that it renders properly. Also, quoted the error message so it looks more attractive.

Comment: I never could get those export formats to work either during my brief year of working on that platform. I always figured that it was a permissions issue or those modules weren't installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `WITH COLUMN NAMES`. So your query could look like

```
select  * from siebel.S_ORG_EXT;  
OUTPUT TO 'C:\Siebel SQLs\Account.xls' FORMAT EXCEL
DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '' 
WITH COLUMN NAMES;
```

Comment: I tried the same query still getting the error message syntax error at line 2.

Comment: Ah.. I thought you issue is the column names. Well.. rethinking. Export to Excel seems not to be supported by iq.